# Getting information from 3 tables SQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

Im making a blog like system using HTML, CSS, PHP and MySQl. 
The site is made up of three tables.

user (**id**, username, password, email)
posts (**postid**, title, post)
comments (**postid**, **id**, comment, commentid) postid coming from posts and id from user.

I am trying to display all of the comments and the users username who left them for a certain post.

When i use this query in phpmyadmin:
SELECT user.username, comments.comment FROM user INNER JOIN comments on user.id=comments.id where postid=1

It shows what i need.

When i add it into php i get a blank page.

```
<?php
//echo "1";
session_start();

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or die("Couldn't connect");
mysql_select_db("com541blog") or die("Couldn't connect to database");

//echo "2";
//$postid = $_GET['type'];
$_SESSION['postid'] = $postid;

//echo "3";
$query_comments = mysql_query("SELECT user.username as username, comments.comment as comment     FROM user INNER JOIN comments on user.id=comments.id WHERE postid='1'");

$info = mysql_fetch_array($query_comments);

$username = $info['username'];
$comment = $info['comment'];

echo $username;                         
echo $comment;

?>
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Sounds like your original question(s) have now been answered (as you're no longer getting a blank page, rather an unexpected resultset), and you're now moving on to the next step in debugging your app.  You should 1. upvote everyone who has helped, and 2. accept the solution that ultimately helped, then 3. create a new question, being precise in your explanations.  "Eg in my database there is 3 row that have the post id 1" - in which _table_ are these three rows?? Help us help you by being careful to frame your questions well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line has an error I suspect, ie missing 'c' near the end of 'connect'.

`include("db_connet.php");` should be `include("db_connect.php");`

Also, missing a semi-colon `;`.  This:

```
$query_comments = ("SELECT user.username, comments.comment 
                    FROM user INNER JOIN comments on user.id=comments.id 
                    where postid=1")
```

Should read:

```
$query_comments = ("SELECT user.username, comments.comment 
                    FROM user INNER JOIN comments on user.id=comments.id 
                    where postid=1");
```

Also, not bad practice to qualify each of your column names with a table name eg `user.username` as you're doing.  But you might prefer eg the following more concise syntax using table aliases:

```
$query_comments = ("SELECT u.username, c.comment 
                    FROM user u INNER JOIN comments c on u.id = c.id 
                    where c.postid = 1");
```

(Note the table aliases don't need to be a single letter, so can be handy reducing a table name such as "ManufacturerSuppliedPartsListData_Feb01", to eg "mpl", without losing their meaning.  Or eg if you've got "Customers" and "Credit" instead of just "c" you might use eg "cust" and "cred")

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :) was a mistake in a few of my pages. Still got a blank page :(

Comment: @Space so do some basic debugging... eg add an `echo "1";` before the `include`. `echo "2";` after the include.  What now?  Still blank?  Remark-out the `include` and then what? etc...

Comment: @Space also include a copy of your `db_connect` code in your question (ie edit your question, don't add it as a comment).  Have you any evidence that this `db_connect` file actually works?

Comment: I have put an echo before and after the db_connect.php and one before the $query_comments. None of them work but when i comment out the $query_comments they all work. Yes the db_connect file works, have it on every page and they work fine.

Comment: @Space You're missing a semi-colon at the end of your `$query_comments` line.

Comment: @Space still yet to see your db_connect.php file.  Appreciate that it works OK, but still might help to see it to help debug this issue.

Comment: @Space, James's answer has you sorted ;-)

Comment: i have added to the code above. Added the semi-colon, got back one row, in my database there is 3 row that have the post id 1

Comment: @Space, indeed you have, thanks.  I appreciate it.  Since there were several bugs here, and several people helped out... when you get some more rep you might make a point of coming back and dishing out some upvotes to the others.

Answer (score 2):

You're not executing any query.

```
$rs = mysql_query($query_comments);
$info = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
```

Comment: +1 Brilliant in its simplicity ;-).  How did I see spelling errors and missing semi-colons, yet miss that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `mysql_query` in PHP ... Else your query will not be executed

Like :

```
$query_comments = mysql_query("SELECT user.username, comments.comment FROM user INNER JOIN comments on user.id=comments.id where where postid=1");
```

Comment: Added them but still a blank page

Comment: @DavidLavery Try to add mysql_query in front of your SELECT query like I said in my "EDIT section"...

Comment: Have added it but still nothing

Comment: have you selected a database by using the `mysql_select_db ( string $database_name )` statement just after connection settings ?

Comment: Yeah it is in the db_connect.php

Comment: @Sepster yes, aliases not needed, it improves readability btw

Comment: @pouki06 Aliases on _tables_ improves readability.  Aliases on columns, when not necessary, just add redundant noise IMHO.

Comment: @Sepster That is fair enough ;)

Comment: @Space up to you.  I would, as they just add more that can go wrong in this case.  Refer my answer below with an example that you may prefer, but again - it's personal taste.  Whatever you do, make sure you update your code to show us what you're working with, assuming you still have an error/problem.