# Join 3 database tables together in PHP

Tags: php

I have 3 database tables that I need information from. The information I need is indented.

```
--products 
    --product_image
--order_options 
    --option_value
--order_products
    --product_id
```

Right now I have the following code

```
foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id= $product_id") as $row)
    order_product[] = $row;

foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM order_options WHERE order_id= $order_id") as $row)
    order_size[] = $row;

foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM order_products WHERE order_id= $order_id") as $row)
    order_source[] = $row;
```

*(The `order_id` comes from an `$order_id = $_GET['id'];` earlier in the script.)*

I am wanting to place all three select statements into a single query. I've seen this done but never really understood anything I found (i.e. [an old question from this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682983/getting-information-from-3-tables-sql-php)) I understood the [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1OLrfjHDyw) I watched and managed to change the above into the below:

```
foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM [order_products] as opro INNER JOIN order_options as oopt ON opro.order_id = oopt.order_id") as $row)
        $order_variables[] = $row;
```

Although when I run this I receive this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/www/libraries/phppwinty/print.php on line 35
```

So how can I get a successful `JOIN` between these `3` tables?

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work. Idea: join products by product_id, and order_options by order_id with order_products on the specfied ids:

```
SELECT orderproducts.product_id, orderoptions.option_value, products.product_image

FROM order_products as orderproducts

INNER JOIN order_options as orderoptions ON orderproducts.order_id = orderoptions.order_id
INNER JOIN products as products ON orderproducts.product_id = products.product_id

WHERE 
orderproducts.order_id = $order_id AND
orderproducts.product_id = $product_id
```

Comment: I created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ebe2z/ I placed your code into my script and still receive the same error?

Comment: this query grabs the product_id, option_value, and product_image already. you only need one query call, not 3.